# How to stop retyping "ssh user@domain.com" over and over

Tags: unix, ssh, scp, iterm, productivity-power-tools

My workflow always consists of opening a new terminal window, typing `ssh user@domain.com` (or `scp`) followed by `cd remote/directory/of/project`

The domain is long and hard to type, as well as it being a big file path so this takes me ~20 seconds every time. What's the canonical, efficient way to do this that you would see a senior dev doing?

Comment: Put it in a script file you run when opening your new terminal window.

Comment: put `user@domain.com` in your .ssh/config with a convenient alias. For the path your could search your command history (Ctrl+R), use an alias (in your .bashrc) or us a soft link `ln -s remote/directory/of/project ~`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For not retyping `ssh user@domain.com` that often, you can put it in you `.ssh/config`:

```
Host my_alias
HostName domain.com
User user
```

Afterwards, you can just type ssh `my_alias`.

For not retyping the path, you can

- put the path in an alias in your `.bashrc` (`alias cd_my_proj='cd remote/directory/of/project'`)
- look it up in your bash history (usually with Ctrl+R)
- use a soft link (`ln -s remote/directory/of/project ~`)
- keep the path open in a tmux (or screen) session

You may also google these pointers for more details (like how to save tmux session and further details in your .ssh/config)

Answer (score 2):

You can create a script file with the commands you want to execute so you can just execute it instead of manually typing your ssh/scp/cd commands every time you have to do so.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).